# Where is css file of my menu?I have joomla site

Tags: css, joomla, menu, where-clause, styling

Can't style my menu css,i tried to change in master-ccda(my site www.blobus.on.kg)It helps for 5 minutes than changed back.Please help me to find place where i can change it.

Comment: You changed the cached version of the CSS ?

Comment: What template are you using and what module? Try to find the non cached version. You can search the contents of all your files for .menu-item-bg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a rocketheme/gantry template. Your website has compression/caching enabled for the css. This is enabled either by the template settings or another compression/caching system plugin. Therefore what you get as a final css file, is a dynamically generated compressed css file. Any edits you are doing on this file are getting lost, as soon as the system will generate a new final master.css file.

You need to disable these functions while you are building your website. Doing so will stop the compression of all the css files into one and you will see what rules and from which files your menu and other elements/sections of your website inherit their styles.

In addition keep in mind that it is best to avoid making changes on the core files of your template/extensions. 
**Gantry templates** allow you to create a **custom css** file where you can put your own css overrides.

The custom css file need to be place inside the css folder of your template and usually needs to have a name of this convention: **rt_templatename-custom.css**.